# Is there anything wrong with this code for show (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller:

```rb
   def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @goal = @user.goals.find(params[:id])
        render :template => 'goals/show'
    end
```

View (show.html.erb):

```rb
<%= @goal.text %>
```

I have added hello, world text just to check whether the link is going to show.html.erb. It is. The problem is that <%= @goal.text %> turns up blank.

Have been dealing with this for days... I'd really appreciate your help.

create and new in the controller:

```rb
    def new
        @user = current_user
        @goal = @user.goals.new

        #for index
        @goal = @user.goals
    end


    def create 
        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        @goal = @user.goals.create(goal_params)

        if @goal.save
            redirect_to new_user_goal_path, notice: "Success!~"
        else 
            redirect_to new_user_goal_path, alert: "Failure!"
        end
    end 

    private
        def goal_params
            params.require(:goal).permit(:text)
        end
```

I list the goals in the new.html.erb:

```rb
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @user.goals.each do |goal| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to goal.text, goal_path(@user,goal)%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<h2>Add a goal:</h2>
<%= form_for([@user, @user.goals.build]) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

One point -- I have been so focused on fixing this that it seems that create doesn't work now. I must have changed something in my desperation. If you could please let me know what mistake you see in there as well, I'd really appreciate it.

also route:

```rb
  devise_for :users

  resource :user do
    resources :goals, shallow: true
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

UPDATE:
my schema, just in case:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_07_02_174954) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "goals", "users"
end
```

Comment: You can do `<%= @goal.inspect %>` to actually see what's in the `@goal` variable. Maybe it is not what you think it is.

Comment: looks like youre using the same id for user as you are for goal. That's probably wrong.

Comment: @Eyeslandic Brilliant, thank you. It turns up this: ```#<Goal id: 1, text: nil, created_at: "2019-07-03 18:47:13", updated_at: "2019-07-03 18:47:13", user_id: 1>``` Does this mean text is not saved?

Comment: @Eyeslandic Also goal id is 1 for all goals (I have ~20). And created at and updated at are same for all. What does this mean?

Comment: Obviously, your goal.text is empty in database.

Comment: Could you also provide your ```create``` and ```new``` methods and your ```index.html.erb```?

Comment: What is the output if you do ```Goal.all.pluck(:id, :text, :user_id)```?

Comment: @B-M Thank you - posted.

Comment: @B-M This: ```[[1, nil, 1], [2, nil, 1], [3, nil, 1], [4, nil, 1], [5, nil, 1], [6, nil, 1], [7, nil, 1], [8, nil, 1], [9, nil, 1], [10, nil, 1], [11, nil, 1], [12, "lol....", 1], [13, "Finally...", 1], [14, "WOW\r\n", 1], [15, "OK", 1], [16, "haha", 1], [17, "lol", 1], [18, "akfkalfasdfasdf", 1], [19, "hmm?", 1], [20, "haha", 1], [21, "what", 1], [22, "hmm", 1]]```

Comment: @B-M To clarify - for goals 1-11, the text I inputted was really nil.

Comment: Try this in your new.html.erb:
```<%= form_for @goal, url: {controller: "goals", action: "create"} do |form| %>```

Comment: Oh, so the create was working? You wanted ```nil``` in your text?

Comment: @B-M It was working only a few days ago. I must have changed something, likely in the controller or the routes (it was resources: users do... before. I changed it according to someone's suggestion). As for some of the goals being nil, that was when I just clicked on create button several times without inputting anything... I just tried your suggestion, and a strange error popped up: ```undefined method `to_key' for #<Goal::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007ffa84d07358>
Did you mean?  to_set
               to_ary```

Comment: @thebot: did you see the comment from marcusshep? It highlights the core of the issue you're having.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you. When I use user_id instead of id for user, it returns: ```Couldn't find User without an ID```

Comment: What about changing ```@goal = @user.goals.find(params[:id])``` to ```@goal = @user.goals.find(params[:goal_id])```

Comment: @B-M Thank you. Returns this error: ```Couldn't find Goal without an ID```

Comment: @thebot: what we're trying to tell you is that you need separate ids for user and goal. Could be id/goal_id or user_id/id or maybe even something else, depending on how you arrange your routes. But the values for those ids don't magically appear out of thin air, obviously. You have to generate proper links, for instance. Could look like this: `<%= goal_path(@goal, user_id: current_user.id) %>` (note the "could". There's infinite number of ways of writing this)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I understand, thank you. I've tried all -- naturally, I started with different id for each -- and they have returned errors. Hence my confusion and coming here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this might work for you:

**goals_controller.rb:**

```rb
def new
  @user = current_user
  @goal = Goal.new
end

def create
  @goal = current_user.goals.new(goal_params)
  if @goal.save
    redirect_to new_user_goal_path, notice: "Success!~"
  else
    redirect_to new_user_goal_path, alert: "Failure!"
  end
end

def show
  @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
end

private
def goal_params
  params.require(:goal).permit(:text)
end
```

**show.html.erb:**

```html
<%= @goal.text %>
```

**new.html.erb:**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @user.goals.each do |goal| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to goal.text, goal_path(goal.id)%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<h2>Add a goal:</h2>
<%= form_for([@user, @goal]) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you. I get this error: ```No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"goals", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]```

Comment: @thebot, Sorry, I forgot ```.id```. Try this: ```<td><%= link_to goal.text, goal_path(goal.id)%></td>```